# why does it shows truncated incorrect integer values when using char(salary,'$99,999)

Tags: mariadb

I tried the following query:

```
select 
    concat(e.first_name,"  ",e.last_name) as 'employee name',
    char(s.salary*15/100,'$99,999') as 'No.Of Dollors'
from 
    employees e
join 
    salaries s
    on e.emp_no=s.emp_no 
group by 
    e.emp_no,s.emp_no;
```

It raises:

> truncated incorrect integer vale:'$99,999'

Comment: According to docs [char() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/char-function/) does not use masks

Comment: `CONCAT('$', FORMAT(s.salary*15/100, 2))`

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving a *warning* as '$99,999' is not an integer. The [CHAR() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/char-function/) expects integer(s) as input.

As suggested by McNets: it seems you are trying to use the [CHAR() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/char-function/) for something it is not intended to do. The CHAR() function accepts integers as input and will interpret each integer as a character code, returning corresponding, concatenated character(s) as a string.

The function you seem to be looking for is the [FORMAT() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/format/), which will format a numerical value and returns a string. This will however not prepend a currency symbol, so that should then be added via the [CONCAT() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/format/).

As suggested by Kumar: the following will produce the result (I expect) you wish to achieve:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(e.first_name,"  ",e.last_name) AS 'employee name',
    CONCAT('$', FORMAT(s.salary*15/100, 2)) AS 'No.Of Dollors'
FROM
    employees e
JOIN
    salaries s
    ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no 
GROUP BY
    e.emp_no, s.emp_no;
```